# Pass custom variable to Bitrise flow through the API

Tags: android, continuous-integration, bitrise

I am setting up a Bitrise on an Android app. I have everything set that is related to the flow, the thing is that I have a custom python builder which requires a parameter. My build-flow is triggered through API, which is working as expected - the only thing missing is passing that parameter to the build script.

*What I have currently:*

- I have added an env-variable; named **PARAM**
- My JSON body, that triggers the build

  ```
  {
        "hook_info":{
            "type":"bitrise"
        },
        "build_params":{
            "branch":"master",
            "workflow_id":"test_args_script",
            "commit_message":"Triggered from postman",
            "environments":[
                {
                    "mapped_to":"PARAM",
                    "value":"123456",
                    "is_expand":true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ```
- On the Bitrise flow I have a **script** step which is actually calling the python script as follows: **python builder.py $PARAM**

*EXPECTATIONS*:

My expectations are that the value that will be passed to the script will be the same as the one in the API payload (123456).

If anyone has recently worked on something similar, or if any of you guys can point me out to documentation that will help me to achieve the above I will be really thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the way. The problem on my end was that I had an env-variable already named the same as the one variable that has been passed from the API. After changing the name to a different one, I was able to get the parameter and pass it to the build script. If anyone needs more info, give me a shout and I can post the payload along with the flow settings.

Comment: You can also run remote scripts (and do the API and other dynamic stuff) using https://bitrise.io/integrations/steps/remote-script-runner